# Can my teammate who has only a MacBook, run my Windows Xamarin.IOS project?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.IOS project that I created with my Windows Visual Studio.
With VS connected to my MacBook, I run the project on my iPad connected to my Mac.

I want to send to my teammate the Windows Xamarin.IOS project so he can run it on his IOS device (iPhone) and test it?

Comment: Yes, of course.  Couldn't you just have tried it in the same time it took to post this?

Comment: How? He doesn't have a Windows laptop to open the project.

Comment: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/

Comment: if you just want to distribute for testing on devices, use appcenter.ms

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You have two options: You can either just directly send the app to your friend's iOS device, or send the project using Git.

**Option 1:**  The steps are mentioned in Microsoft's officials docs for [Pair to Mac for Xamarin.iOS development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/). Here are the pre-requisites:

> Before following the instructions in this guide, complete the following steps:
>
> - On a Windows machine, install Visual Studio 2019
> - On a Mac, install Xcode and Visual Studio for Mac
>         You must manually open Xcode after installing so that it can add any additional components.
>
> If you would prefer not to install Visual Studio for Mac, Visual Studio 2019 can automatically configure the Mac build host with Xamarin.iOS and Mono. You must still install and run Xcode. For more information, see Automatic Mac provisioning.

**Option 2:** From my experience, the best way of doing it is using git (like GitHub) though. Just have him

1. Install VS for Mac and XCode (and its additional components prompted on load)
2. Pull the latest code of you Xamarin.iOS project from the shared Git repository
3. Rebuild All and build it onto the test device. (He might have some provisioning profile issues that is resolved in other stackoverflow questions)

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question the OP asked,  He already has this setup working.  He was asking about sharing with a colleague who only has a Mac.

Comment: He mentions, "want to send to my teammate the Windows Xamarin.IOS project so he can run it on his IOS device (iPhone) and test it". So I was mentioning that he has two options: he can either send the project using Git, or he can just directly send the app to his friend's iOS device.